# How to POST image to django rest API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am not too practiced in handling image files, and I am very confused about posting and handling an image using my django REST API. I am using a python script as client just for testing (will be ios app eventually).

Anyone who can help me receive an image file, and save it locally on the server would be greatly appreciated.

Client:

```
i = Image.open('image.jpeg')
upload = {
    'id': 3,
    'picture': i
}
r = requests.post(ip, data=upload, stream=True)
print(r.text)
```

Server:

```
class Picture_Upload(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        f = request.data['picture']
        return Response(f.content)
```

Comment: try request.POST['picture'] and then read()

Comment: @riNg which read()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use [MultiPartParser](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#multipartparser) to parse the form data so that you can read it on your APIView, and surely that we have to send data as `multipart/form-data`. Like so:

```py
upload = {
    'picture': open('image.jpeg', 'rb')
}

data = {
    'id': 3
}

resp = requests.post('/upload_url/', files=upload, data=data)
```

and your view:

```py
class Picture_Upload(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser, )

    def post(self, request):
        picture = request.data['picture']
        id = request.data['id']

        # Use your model to handle the uploaded file

        return Response(status=200)
```